# Как вывести рандомные изображения с помощью gallery modx?

Tags: php, modx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать вывод 3х рандомных изображений с помощью gallery modx?
Есть запрос:

```
[[!Gallery? &album=`1` &thumbWidth=`215` &thumbHeight=`140` &thumbTpl=`gallery` &imageWidth=`1100` &imageHeight=`800` &limit=`3` &sort=`rand`]]
```

Он выводит изображения, но при перезагрузке страницы они остается прежними, меняется лишь порядок(т.к. &sort=`rand`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [issues](https://github.com/splittingred/Gallery/issues/258) компонента **Gallery** как-то поднимался этот вопрос. Решается путём внесения изменений в файл `/core/components/gallery/model/gallery/galitem.class.php`

Удалить строку *(примерно 298-я)*: `$sort = $modx->getOption('sort',$scriptProperties,'rank');`

Заменить:

```
if ($modx->getCacheManager() && $cache = $modx->cacheManager->get($cacheKey)) {
```

на:

```
$sort = $modx->getOption('sort',$scriptProperties,'rank');  
if ($modx->getCacheManager() && $sort != 'rand' && $cache = $modx->cacheManager->get($cacheKey)) {
```